# How do you add the google app launcher (waffle menu) to a Google Site?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-sites-2016

We are creating an intranet style site via Google Sites & would like to include the standard Google app launcher menu (waffle) at the top so users can easily get into email etc from the intranet. Any idea where I can find code to embed this?

I've added links in the menu for now but would be keen to keep the usual google menu format users are already familiar with.

Comment: You should create a project in Google Cloud Platform, the add the Google Apps Martketplace SDK, publish as app. Ref. https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish